# Golden ratio rectangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, applications, golden-ratio

I'm designing a layout and I would like to use four golden ratio rectangles. The total width of the layout is 960px. How do I find the height (x)? Below is a diagram of the layout.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but wouldn't $x$ just be $$ 960 \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$$

Comment: Ah, a diagram. I guess you want all four small rectangles to be golden?

Comment: @Gerry In the future, please read the question before commenting; the link was there from the start, even before it was replaced by the actual diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding the required height amounts to expressing $a$ and $c$ in terms of the height $h = a+b$. I will do this below; denote with $\phi$ the golden ratio.

---

We have that $\dfrac h a =\phi$, i.e. $a = \dfrac h \phi$. Now $d = \dfrac h2$, and $\dfrac c d = \phi$.

Using some trivial algebra, we obtain:

$$c = \phi d = \frac\phi2 h$$

Thus we have reduced to solving the equation:

$$960 = 2a + c = \left(\frac2\phi+\frac\phi 2\right)h$$

In conclusion, $h = \dfrac{960}{\frac2\phi+\frac\phi 2} \approx 469.42$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lord_Farin!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

golden ratio is

(a+b)/a = a/b

so assuming that a is width, and b is height, you have:
$$
(960 + h)/960 = 960/h \\
960^2 = 960h + h^2
$$
a simple quadratic equation to solve, and the result is
$$
h = 480*(\sqrt 5-1) \approx 593.3
$$

Comment: It is not the whole diagram that is supposed to be golden; it's the four constituent rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to calculate this is with using ratios:

ϕ/(ϕ+2)=x/960

solve for x: 960/(1+2/ϕ) which results in 429.32505